# How to specify Code Style settings in a Qt Creator `.pro.shared` file?

Tags: qt, qt-creator

I can see from the documentation on https://qt-project.org/doc/qtcreator-2.6/creator-sharing-project-settings.html how to create a `.pro.shared` file that standardizes Editor settings.

But:  is it possible to standardize Qt Creator's "Code Style" settings in a `.pro.shared` file, and if so, what is the syntax?

Answer (score 1):

There is currently no UI way of doing that, not sure if we will add one at some point.

So you will need to do this manually: Set it up for a user, close the project to make sure the .user file is saved and copy copy the file into a .shared file. Remove everything you do not want to share (keep ProjectExplorer.Project.Updater.FileVersion!), while keeping the XML structure intact. You are a developer, I am sure you will manage:-)

Oh, make sure to use the oldest Qt Creator you want to support (IIRC this was introduced in 2.5, so going older than that won't help) to create the template. Creator will upgrade settings while reading them but it can not downgrade, so .shared files that are too new are going to be ignored.

Comment: Thanks.  I figured out how to include other Editor settings in the `.pro.shared` file (see the XML on [my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13993972/64860)).  But the Code Style settings — such as the "Add extra padding to conditions if they would align to the next line" checkbox — don't seem to be included in the `.pro.user` file; they're stored in `~/.config/QtProject/qtcreator/codestyles/Cpp/qt*.xml`.  I'm asking whether there's some way to specify Code Style settings, such as that checkbox, in a `.pro.shared` file.

Comment: Not 100% sure... The rule of thumb is: If it is listed in "Projects" mode (Projects icon on the left side), then it is in the .user file.